# error installing lang/perl5.30 on FreeBSD 12.0

Tags: perl, freebsd

Clean installation of FreeBSD 12.0 updated to last patch.

Trying to install Perl: `portmaster lang/perl5.30`

Error: `malloc.c:1242:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_perl`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't know how FreeBSD handles patching the source code its compiling, but perl-5.30.0 needs the following patch applied to build properly on systems which use perl's malloc() library:
[v5.31.0-13-g9629b6dc1d](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blobdiff/cc16d262eb72677cdda2aa9395e943818b85ba38..9629b6dc1d6296e0d3a6a5dbfd0f672b4b2021ca:/malloc.c)

Answer (score 1):

1.go to /usr/ports/lang/per5.30

2.run "make config" and deselect PERL_MALLOC option

3.now retry make install

Comment: disabling MALLOC support is not an option.